# How to enable mongodb on php:7.2-fpm-alpine?

Tags: php, mongodb, alpine-linux

I am trying to enable mongodb on php:7.2-fpm-alpine, and I am not able to see the mongodb extension loaded in php.ini

Here is some additional info:

```
# mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd
OpenSSL version: LibreSSL 2.5.5
allocator: system
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

and

```
    # php -i | grep mongo 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongodb.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongodb.so: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongodb.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongodb.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/20_mongodb.ini,
```

Based on that warning I guess that the mongo extension is missing, but doesn't that conflict the info retrieved by the # mongo --version command?

I also tried to look for mongodb.so using find / -name 'mongo*.*'.

What is the best way to install and enable mongodb driver on php:7.2-fpm-alpine?

**Update:**
Additional info when I run this command: # apk list -a | grep "mongo" I see:
mongodb-3.4.4-r0 x86_64 {mongodb} (AGPL3) [installed]

Comment: There is nothing mongodb related in this image.

Comment: @D.SM can you please elaborate? Is there an alternative solution or a hack? what is the mongoDB that is installed on the server: MongoDB shell version v3.4.4 ?

Comment: If *you* installed anything mongodb-related yourself into a *container* based on this image, that is important information that should have been in the question.

Comment: @D.SM I don't understand your comment, what did I install on the container that wasn't mentioned in the question?

Comment: You did not say that you installed anything, which is my point.

Comment: @D.SM I see. I didn't think it's relevant to the question, since I thought Mongo is already installed. Should I update the question now with the Dockerfile?

Comment: You seem to have a solution already, thus this is more feedback for the future.

Comment: Thank you @D.SM will do.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more research and digging, I ended up installing PECL on the server.

Installing PECL on Alpine:

```
apk update && apk upgrade
apk add --no-cache php7-pear php7-dev gcc musl-dev make
```

Once PECL was installed, I ran this command:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

after mongodb was installed I added "extension=mongodb.so" inside /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/20_mongodb.ini

and finally I restarted the docker container.

After taking all these steps, I could see Mongodb installed and enabled by looking at phpinfo()

Now when I run:

```
php -i | grep mongo
```

I see

```
mongodb
libmongoc bundled version => 1.17.0
```

I am assuming the latest Mongodb(libmongoc) is the PHP package vs the "MongoDB shell version v3.4.4" which is the server level package.

I hope someone will find this information helpful.